# Terraform fails on creating network with libvirt provider

Tags: terraform

I wanted to spin up a test environment locally using the description from this stackoverflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58607900/4397899

The main.tf looks like

```
################################################################################
# ENV VARS
################################################################################

# https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html

variable "VM_COUNT" {
  default = 3
  type = number
}

variable "VM_USER" {
  default = "developer"
  type = string
}

variable "VM_HOSTNAME" {
  default = "ci-vm"
  type = string
}

variable "VM_IMG_URL" {
  default = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/release/ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img"
  type = string
}

variable "VM_IMG_FORMAT" {
  default = "qcow2"
  type = string
}

variable "VM_CIDR_RANGE" {
  default = "10.10.10.10/24"
  type = string
}


################################################################################
# PROVIDERS
################################################################################

# instance the provider
provider "libvirt" {
  uri = "qemu:///system"
}


################################################################################
# DATA TEMPLATES
################################################################################

# https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html

# https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/cloudinit_config.html
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("${path.module}/cloud_init.cfg")
  vars = {
    VM_USER = var.VM_USER
  }
}

data "template_file" "network_config" {
  template = file("${path.module}/network_config.cfg")
}


################################################################################
# RESOURCES
################################################################################

resource "libvirt_pool" "vm" {
  name = "${var.VM_HOSTNAME}_pool"
  type = "dir"
  path = "/tmp/terraform-provider-libvirt-pool-ubuntu"
}

# We fetch the latest ubuntu release image from their mirrors
resource "libvirt_volume" "vm" {
  count  = var.VM_COUNT
  name   = "${var.VM_HOSTNAME}-${count.index}_volume.${var.VM_IMG_FORMAT}"
  pool   = libvirt_pool.vm.name
  source = var.VM_IMG_URL
  format = var.VM_IMG_FORMAT
}

# Create a public network for the VMs
resource "libvirt_network" "vm_public_network" {
   name = "${var.VM_HOSTNAME}_network"
   mode = "nat"
   domain = "${var.VM_HOSTNAME}.local"
   addresses = ["${var.VM_CIDR_RANGE}"]
   dhcp {
    enabled = true
   }
   dns {
    enabled = true
   }
}

# for more info about paramater check this out
# https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/blob/master/website/docs/r/cloudinit.html.markdown
# Use CloudInit to add our ssh-key to the instance
# you can add also meta_data field
resource "libvirt_cloudinit_disk" "cloudinit" {
  name           = "${var.VM_HOSTNAME}_cloudinit.iso"
  user_data      = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
  network_config = data.template_file.network_config.rendered
  pool           = libvirt_pool.vm.name
}

# Create the machine
resource "libvirt_domain" "vm" {
  count  = var.VM_COUNT
  name   = "${var.VM_HOSTNAME}-${count.index}"
  memory = "1024"
  vcpu   = 1

  cloudinit = "${libvirt_cloudinit_disk.cloudinit.id}"

  # TODO: Automate the creation of public network
  network_interface {
    network_id = "${libvirt_network.vm_public_network.id}"
    #network_id = "6d8e2494-835d-4baf-a14f-3a5c705febcc"
    #network_name = "vm_docker_network"
    network_name = "${libvirt_network.vm_public_network.name}"
  }

  # IMPORTANT
  # Ubuntu can hang is a isa-serial is not present at boot time.
  # If you find your CPU 100% and never is available this is why.
  #
  # This is a known bug on cloud images, since they expect a console
  # we need to pass it:
  # https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1573095
  console {
    type        = "pty"
    target_port = "0"
    target_type = "serial"
  }

  console {
    type        = "pty"
    target_type = "virtio"
    target_port = "1"
  }

  disk {
    volume_id = "${libvirt_volume.vm[count.index].id}"
  }

  graphics {
    type        = "spice"
    listen_type = "address"
    autoport    = true
  }
}


################################################################################
# TERRAFORM CONFIG
################################################################################

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}
```

The network_config.cfg looks like this

```
version: 2
ethernets:
  ens3:
     dhcp4: true
```

Steps to Reproduce Issue

Run

```
terraform init
terraform apply
```

Then I get the error message:

```
Error: Error creating libvirt network: virError(Code=38, Domain=0, Message='error creating bridge interface ci-vm_network-br: Numerical result out of range')
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is here:

default = "10.10.10.10/24"

you have defined a network address and not a subnet. Try and change the IP address to a subnet address it should work.